# How to pass formula as parameter from textfile to vbscript function

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to pass the below formula as a parameter from text file to the vbscript function, but receiving the unknown run time error at run time.

**textfile:**

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H2),"""",(CONCATENATE(""0"",K2)))
```

**VBS function:**

```
Function PopulateFormula(fmula,filename)

Set Destfile = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set DWB = Destfile.Workbooks.Open(filename)

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set FormulaLogic = fso.OpenTextFile(textfile)   

                fmula=FormulaLogic.ReadLine()

              DWB.Worksheets(1).Range(M2:M2).Formula = fmula

End function
```

The above functions works correctly if I hardcode the `fmula` variable with

`fmula= =IF(ISBLANK(H2),"""",(CONCATENATE(""0"",K2)))`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you read the fmula properly from the file?

Add a statement to check it:

```
fmula=FormulaLogic.ReadLine()
MsgBox fmula
DWB.Worksheets(1).Range(M2:M2).Formula = fmula
```